# Finding an Orthogonal Basis for a Span of Vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, orthogonality

I have been given a span of vectors, $\{(3,0,-1,2), (-6,0,2,4)\}$, and am to find an orthogonal basis. How do I go about doing this? The answer they give is  $\{(3,0,-1,2), (-5,21,-3,6)\}$. Any help appreciated in understanding this!

Comment: Gram-Schmidt$\ $

Comment: Also the answer "they" gave is wrong (or you mistyped the original vectors).

Comment: @Bye_World Double checked a couple times just to make sure. It being wrong makes more sense to me... I had originally used the Gram-Schmidt process and will go back to it. Thanks!

Comment: Note that since you only have to find an _orthogonal_ basis, you can skip the normalization steps in Gram-Schmidt.